# Prove that one of x,y,z is smaller than 3 and one is bigger than 5 if...

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

If $x+y+z=12$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=54$ then prove that one has to be smaller or equal to 3 and one has to be bigger or equal than 5.

So I got that $xy+yz+zx=45$ and with that I had a function with x,y,z as zeros: $f(a)=a^3-12a^2+45a-k$, where k=xyz.
I get that $f'(a)=3(a-3)(a-5)$, but I can't prove what I need with that.

Comment: Like $x\ge 5$ and $3\ge z$

Comment: what kind of numbers are given?

Comment: x,y,z are real numbers

Comment: Assume $x,y,z$ have to be real. Your equation for $f'(a)$ shows there are two turning points for $f(a)$. Concretely, $f(a)$ has a local maximum at $a=3$ and a local minimum at $a=5$. Then one of the roots of $f(a)$ is before or at $a=3$, and one after or at $a=5$.

Comment: Why is that true? I thought of the same thing but I can't explain it.

Comment: If at the local maximum $a=3$, $f(a)< 0$, then $f(a)$ has only one real root and two complex roots. Analogous for the local minimum at $a=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out the comment by peterwhy.

Assume first that $x,y,z$ are all distinct. W.l.o.g. we can assume that $x>y>z$. Then $x,y,z$ are the three zeros of $f(a)$. By Rolle's theorem $f'(a)$ must have a zero between $z$ and $y$ and another zero between $y$ and $x$. But you know the zeros of $f'(a)$, so this shows that
$$z<3<y<5<x.$$

Ok. That leaves us with the case when two or more of them are equal. Without loss of generality we assume that $x=y$. Then you get the system $2x+z=12$, $2x^2+z^2=54$. I'm sure you can find the solutions of that system, and verify the claim in this case also.

Comment: This is the best one that has been explained. Thank you. I have posted also an easier solution, take a look pls and see if something is wrong.

Comment: Done checking, @Mirza :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got:
Let $x\ge y\ge z> 3$, then we that we can write x,y,z as follow: $a=x+3,b=y+3,c=z+3$. Then we have that $a+b+c=3$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=9$. With that we have that $ab+bc+ca=0$, but bcs $x,y,z>3>0$ then are a,b,c positive too, so it's impossible that ab+bc+ca=0, contradiction. One has to be smaller than 3.
The same thing goes for proving $x\ge 5$, we say that $5>x\ge y\ge z$ and write the same thing and get again that ab+bc+ca=0.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch that needs fleshing out:  We might as well require $x \ge y \ge z$. If $z \gt 3$, let $w=3-z$ and we are thinking of $w$ as small.  The largest $x^2+y^2+z^2$ can be is $(6-2w)^2+2(3+w)^2=54-12w+6w^2$, so $z \lt 3$  If $x \lt 5$, Let $x=5-w$, then the largest $x^2+y^2+z^2$ can be is $2(5-w)^2+(2+2w)^2=54-16w+6w^2$.  In fact there is a solution $5,5,2$

Comment: Pls explain that a little bit, I dont get all the steps you made.

Comment: The problem is that in the first part you use $x^2+y^2+z^2$<49.5 but you cant use that z>3 there...

Comment: I have fixed the first part.

Comment: Ok, I got what you wanted to say but how did you get $(6-2w)^2+2(3+w)^2$ and $2(5-w)^2+(2+2w)^2$?

Comment: For the first, I made $z$ just a little bigger than $3$, and we said $y \ge z$, then got $x$ from the sum being $2$.  Similarly for the second, I made $x$ a little below $5$, then we said $y \le x$, then got $z$ from the sum.